# Allow users to set up your device and to link with Google Home app

Tags: android, firebase, google-smart-home

I develop an smart home on google. I want to be able to allow users to set up your device and to link with Google Home app in my android app. Are there any turial or exemple that help me with that ?

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you are asking about. Can you clarify?

Comment: I finished develop my google action for smart home. In the certification process they told me that in need to allow users to set up your device and to link with Google Home app in my android app. i look on google  for some exemple, tutorial or course to learn how ro add those option in my mobil app. My mobile app is developpe in C# and i use librairie to develop it

Answer (score 0):

Users connect their devices from your service to the Google Assistant through [account linking](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/concepts/account-linking). This process enables them to sign in to your service and authorize Google to access those devices using a standard OAuth token exchange.

You can also support account linking through your native mobile apps with [App Flip](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/implement-app-flip). This enables your mobile app to authorize the user instead of a web endpoint.